# How can I print Excel cell value to Command Prompt / Powershell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, powershell

Say I have a spreadsheet, it has several columns but in column A, each cell going down is numbered in order (1,2,3,etc.).

I want to be able to, for example, click cell A5, and have it open command prompt or powershell, and just read "5".

In theory and oversimplified, it would just "echo %whatever%" and display the value of the selected cell.

Can this be done?

Comment: This can be performed using Macro,, confirm through comments that you can handle it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we want a `CMD` window to display the address and contents of a cell when we **double-click** on it.  Place this event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim st As String
    Cancel = True
    st = " " & Target.Address(0, 0) & " " & Target.Text
    st = "cmd.exe /c echo" & st & " && pause"
    x = Shell(st, 1)
End Sub
```

Then double-click on the cell.

[image]

Comment: It's working properly,,, +10,,, ☺